# Sortable Bar Chart - why do you need to copy the scale?

Tags: d3.js

I am using the approach of Mike Bostock (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705) to transition the bar chart when it needs to be sorted.

It works fine, but despite it's even commented with one line, can someone explain the need to copy the x scale in the function *change()* ?

```
// Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
    ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
    : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
    .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
    .copy();
```

When I try the same thing without the *.copy();* it seems to work as well.

Comment: Not sure why that's there -- as you point out, it's not required here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming...